# How to run a system command, and pipe PID to pidfile?

Tags: ruby, unix

How do I run a command and pipe the resulting pid into a pidfile?

I'm looking for an UNIX command, but if there's a way to do it in Ruby, that'd be nice too.

I tried:

```
bundle exec clockwork clock_local.rb echo $! > #{current_path}/tmp/pids/clockwork.pid
```

and it seems to pipe the entire output to the pidfile rather than just the pid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Ruby's `BEGIN {...}` and `END {...}` to help automatically create and delete PID files. Add these to a Ruby script:

```
BEGIN { File.write("#{ $0 }.pid", $$) }
END { File.delete("#{ $0 }.pid") }
```

You could test that they create a simple PID file with a simple script like:

```
BEGIN { File.write("#{ $0 }.pid", $$) }
END { File.delete("#{ $0 }.pid") }
sleep 60
```

Run it, then, while it's running check the directory it's in for the pid file. After one minute, when the `sleep` expires the PID file should automatically disappear.

Those don't do any exception handling in case the file isn't writable or if it already exists and is locked. `END` will fire off if the script receives <kbd>CNTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and automatically remove the PID file.

Additional things you'd want to add would be tests for an existing PID file, locking the file after creation so it can't be overwritten, which could be done by keeping it open with an exclusive lock (see [`flock`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-i-flock)).

Answer (score 2):

If you run the command in the background you can then store the pid:

```
bundle exec clockwork clock_local.rb & echo $! > tmp/pids/clockwork.pid
```